# How to show loader and animation once per session?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, portfolio

I've coded a personal portfolio website and added all the things I've wanted to add. Now, I am just cleaning it up and working on the UX/ IX stuff to make it more pleasant to navigate and interact with.

With that said, I am trying to make my loader/ loader animation (the spinning bubbles AND the "fade in" aspect) only occur once, when you FIRST enter the website! This is what I have so far, and it works rather nicely. HOWEVER, when you refresh the page or try to navigate back to the homepage from my projects page, there is a rather long waiting screen and then the "fade in" animation comes back.

If anyone could help me, I am trying to make it so that when you refresh or nav back to the home page AFTER you've already seen the loader/ animation, the home page instantly loads without delay, loader, or animation/

Thank you

```js
const navToggle = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle');
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link')
const loader = document.querySelector('.loader');
const main = document.querySelector('.main'); 

function init() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        loader.style.opacity = 0;
        loader.style.display = 'none';
    
        main.style.display = 'block';
        setTimeout(() => (main.style.opacity = 1), 50);
    },2000);
}

init();


navToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('nav-open');
});

navLinks.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.body.classList.remove('nav-open');
    })
})

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    if (!sessionStorage.viewed){
        const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
        loader.className += " hidden";
        sessionStorage.viewed = 1;
    }else{
        const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
        loader.style.display = "none";
    }
})
```

```css
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    overflow: show;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
}

.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #16e0bd;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0);
    animation: grow 1.5s linear infinite;
    margin: -10px;
}

.circle:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #303030;
    animation-delay: 0.75s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes grow {
    50% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="loader">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>

<div class="main" >
```

Comment: use a cookie or localStorage to indicate that this is the first time you entered the site - by the way `navToggle` is null because the element does not exist in your code

Comment: I got it to work using sessionStorage and it has been working for my loader. However, it still shows the animation and the time delay before the animation, which is what I am trying to remove if the user revisits the home page.

Comment: @Bravo would it be helpful if I provided my entire code? Kinda new to this website and to coding, but let me know because I really want to resolve this issue! Thank you so much!